# Prove using the epsilon definition

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, limits, proof-writing, epsilon-delta

I'm trying to prove the below using the $\epsilon$ definition:

> $\epsilon$-definition:  $\;\left|s_n-s\right| \lt \epsilon$
>
> $\lim \limits_{n \to \infty}\frac{(-1)^n\cos \sqrt{n}}{\sqrt[3]{n}}=0$

I'm having trouble with getting the inequality into a form where I can isolate $n$

This is the best I've come up with:

$1 \lt \frac{n\epsilon}{\left(\cos\sqrt{n}\right)^3}$

Comment: Do you mean as $n$ goes to infinity? If so, then just realize the numerator is bounded and make $n$ in the denominator large.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that $$\left| \frac { (-1)^{ n }\cos  \sqrt { n }  }{ \sqrt [ 3 ]{ n }  }  \right| =\frac { \left| (-1)^{ n } \right| \left| \cos  \sqrt { n }  \right|  }{ \left| \sqrt [ 3 ]{ n }  \right|  } <\frac { 1 }{ \left| \sqrt [ 3 ]{ n }  \right|  } <\varepsilon $$
so $$n>\frac { 1 }{ { \varepsilon  }^{ 3 } } $$ and take $${ n }_{ \varepsilon }=\left\lfloor \frac { 1 }{ { \varepsilon  }^{ 3 } }  \right\rfloor $$
it means when ${ n\ge n }_{ \varepsilon  }$ we get $$\left| \frac { (-1)^{ n }\cos  \sqrt { n }  }{ \sqrt [ 3 ]{ n }  } -0 \right| <\varepsilon $$